# How to create new docker container and run it from Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've inherited this `Jenkinsfile` stage that will run a new docker image using `withRun`:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        script {
            docker.image('deployscript:latest').withRun("""\
                -e 'IMAGE=${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_ID}' \
                -e 'CNAME=${IMAGE_NAME}' \
                -e 'PORT=${PORT_1}:80' \
                -e 'PORT=${PORT_2}:443'""") { c ->
                    sh "docker logs ${c.id}"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I believe this method is only meant for testing purposes and actually stops the container once the block is finished. I want this step to actually run the container and stop/restart the previous one if necessary. The documentation out there on this is surprisingly sparse. Please help.

Comment: Try use `bash `for this instead of groovy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the docker container throughout all the stages, thenthe example would look like below:

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
node('master') {
    /* Requires the Docker Pipeline plugin to be installed */
    docker.image('alpine:latest').inside {
       stage('01') {
         sh 'echo STAGE01'
       }
       stage('02') {
         sh 'echo STAGE02'
       }
    }
}
```

**Declarative Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'alpine:latest'
            label 'master'
            args  '-v /tmp:/tmp'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('01') {
            steps {
                sh "echo STAGE01"
            }
        }
        stage('02') {
            steps {
                sh "echo STAGE02"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both scripted and declarative pipelines, The docker container from the alpine image will active for all the stages to finish and only delete if the stage is a success or failure.

But If you would want to control start, stop, restart the container yourself on different stages, you can do it with bash command or by writing a small groovy script wrapping the docker command like below

```
node {
  stage('init') {
    docker create --name myImage1 -v $(pwd):/var/jenkins -w /var/jenkins imageName:tag
  }
  stage('build') {
    // make use of docker command to start, stop and execute some script inside the container
    // same goes for other stage
    //once all done you can remove the container
    docker rm myImage1 
  }
}
```

Comment: I just want my pipeline to replace the already existing container on the host with one that has the new image. I'm not asking about running the container within the pipeline. Does that distinction make sense? I'm pretty new to Docker.

Answer (score 2):

The following will stop the existing container and run a new one with the new image:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        sh "docker stop ${IMAGE_NAME} || true && docker rm ${IMAGE_NAME} || true"
        sh "docker run -d \
            --name ${IMAGE_NAME} \
            --publish ${PORT}:443 \
            ${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_ID}"
    }
}
```